# Kendo line chart tool tip not showing properly

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I am working on net mvc app and I am using kendo 2019.1.115 version. My problem is, in my line chart the mouse pointer is not coordinate correctly with the data displayed on the chart, the dot is colored and the data is displayed but not where the mouse pointer pointed to.

For example:

[image]

In the above image my mouse is pointing to the point which I have highlighted. But the tooltip data is showing for the previous one. I have tried the sample code presented in the kendo site just by copy paste in my project for line chart even the problem remains.

Comment: I'm not sure what is wrong with the configuration, but the [line chart example using kendo 2019.1.115](https://dojo.telerik.com/iCeHUlEN) works fine. Any CSS that might be affecting the ToolTip positioning?

Comment: Please try to refrain from adding "please help" and "thanks in advance" and "hello" to your posts. Technical writing is preferred here. Thanks!